# Facebook watchman everytime looses connection on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04, watchman

Facebook watchman everytime looses connection on ubuntu 16.04. Also it gives error "Error: Watcher took too long to load (WatchmanWatcher)". How can I uninstall watchman on ubuntu?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ watchman watch-project /path/to/your/project/dir
```

and try to run it again.

**Explanation**

With this command

```
$ watchman watch-list
{
    "version": "4.7.0",
    "roots": [
        "~/path/one"
        "~/path/two"
        "~/path/three"
        "~/path/four"
    ]
}
```

you get all the paths that are watched by watchman. If there are too many paths (see roots), watchman takes too long to crawl all the files.

To delete all the paths, run this command:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all
```

To add the new project directories to crawl, add project dir with this command:

```
$ watchman watch-project ~/path/to/project/dir
```

Since you have deleted all the unnecessary folders, now the react packages should take less time to crawl and build.

Hope this helps someone.